# Jquery Expanding div - How to scroll to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically I have a docked footer on my site, which sits at the very bottom of the page. I then  have an empty div "country_slider" which sits under it, and this can be expanded with jQuery's `show` and `hide` functions. The trouble is this, the footer div is already sitting at the bottom of the page via a CSS hack, so when the "country_slider" div expands, it simply goes off the bottom of the page.

I want the div to not only expand, but the page to also scroll down to make it visible. Can anyone tell me the easiest and most hack-free way of doing this?

This is the code I'm using to show the div:

```
$("#country_slide").show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#country_slide").show(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() });
});
```

without an animation:

```
$("#country_slide").show(function() {
    $("html, body").scrollTop($(document).height());
});
```

Comment: Can I get this without the animation?

Comment: Thank you very much, the scrolling is much better but the animation is still there on the expansion, but there is no number in the function so I don't understand

Comment: Use $('#country_slide').show(0, function(){... 
for a comparing have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/459jB/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('#country_slide').show(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#country_slide").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Can I have this without the animation please?